# How to handle nodes of various type using same link list one at a time

Tags: c++

I have a problem description is: i have to make a program for a class management in which two type of student study both country and non country. They have few common attributes but few different ex nationality. Now I have to handle data using link list which use data of student of both type one at a time. Suppose  while handling foreign student one does not care about other and vice versa. I think this can be done using template class but I don't know how to do

Answer (score -2):

As I can tell, you've different types of linked list and you want to treat them equally in a function. If so, You can simply write a function that takes Void* as a parameter, example:

```
int traversLinkedList (void* head) {
//Do your job here, doesn't matter the type of your linked list .. what matter that both types (or more) have the same properties that will be used here
}
```

I hope that's what you want